# how to set the value using Slider Jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-slider

Basically, I have 2 sliders implemented using Jquery. I want to set the value in such a way that, when the first slider is selected say a range ex: 0-36. I want the second slider's max value to be set dynamically to 36. Here is the code. I'm not able to set the value to the second slider pls help.

```
$(function() {
$( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#greenData" ).val( "0 - " + ui.value );
        }
    });
    $( "#greenData" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) );


});

    $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range-min-amber" ).slider({
            range: "min",
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amberData" ).val( "0 - " + ui.value );
            }
        });
        $( "#amberData" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range-min-amber" ).slider( "value" ) );
    });
```

here is the HTML code:

```
<tr>
<td align="right"><label for="greenValue"
                            style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                                Green</label>
                                 </td>
                                 <td>   <div id="slider-range-min">  </div>  </td>
                                 <td> <input type="text" id="greenData" style="border: 0; color: green; font-weight: bold;" readonly="readonly" />  
                          </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td align="right"><label
                            style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                                Amber</label>
                                 </td>
                                 <td id="amberTdId">    <div id="slider-range-min-amber">  </div>    </td>
                                 <td> <input type="text" id="amberData" style="border: 0; color: #FF7E00; font-weight: bold;" readonly="readonly" /> </td>
                    </tr>
```

When I select the green slider's range from 0-36 the value 36 should be set to the slider 2. ie,.. the second sliders range should be from min value:0 and max value: 36

How do i go abt it. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code:

```
$(function() {
$( "#slider-range-min-amber" ).slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amberData" ).val( "0 - " + ui.value );
        }
    });
    $( "#amberData" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range-min-amber" ).slider( "value" ) );
}); 

$(function() {
$( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#greenData" ).val( "0 - " + ui.value );
        var value = ui.value;
        var max = ui.value;
        $( "#slider-range-min-amber" ).slider("option","max",max).slider("value",value);
        $( "#amberData" ).val( "0 - " + ui.value );

    }
});
$( "#greenData" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
```

Or see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QPnxf/1/

Comment: Thanks @phemt, it worked, but the below code matched my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer would be to add the following after your `$('#greenData').val('0 - ' + ui.value);` line:

```
$('#slider-range-min-amber').slider('option', 'max', ui.value);
$('#amberData').val('0 - ' + ui.value);
```

But re-querying the DOM like that is not good for performance. It's better to cache your jQuery objects and re-use them. A more efficient solution would be something like this:

```
$(function() {
  var green = $('#slider-range-min'),
      amber = $('#slider-range-min-amber'),
      greenData = $('#greenData'),
      amberData = $('#amberData'),
      opts = {
        range: 'min',
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 100
      };

  greenData.val('$' + opts.value);
  green.slider(opts).slider('option', 'slide', function(e, ui) {
    greenData.val(opts.min + ' - ' + ui.value);

    // this is the bit that updates the 
    // max value of the second slider
    amber.slider('option', 'max', ui.value);
    amberData.val(opts.min + ' - ' + ui.value);
  });

  amberData.val('$' + opts.value);
  amber.slider(opts).slider('option', 'slide', function(e, ui) {
    amberData.val(opts.min + ' - ' + ui.value);
  });
});
```